# Как получить доступ к внутренним функциям модуля?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как получить доступ к внутренним функциям модуля ?

Например я хочу получить доступ к **watr()** из **gulpfile.js**

**gulpfile.js**

```
var co = require('gulp-cl-v');

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    co.watr();// хочу так, но не получается
});
```

---

модуль который мы подключаем - **gulp-cl-v**

**index.js**

```
var te = function (wayfile) {
    var readable = "none"
    //.....
    function watr(){
        console.log('Вызвали функцию');
    };

    return readable;
}
module.exports = te;
```

Comment: Если модуль не экспортирует функцию -- никак. А вообще это смахивает на [проблему X-Y](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В это примере по сути вы сделали приватной функцию watr.
То есть ваш модуль равен функции `te`. При ее вызове вы получите значение приватной переменной `readable`. Чтобы получить доступ к `watr` как части модуля есть несколько вариантов например вернуть экспортировать объект с методом `watr` или создать конструктор и вернуть его экземпляр.

```
var te = {
    readable: "none",
    watr: function(){
       console.log('Вызвали функцию')
    }
}
module.exports = te;
```

Либо...

```
function te(wayfile){
    this.readable = "none"
    retrun this;
}
te.prototype.watr = function(){
    console.log('Вызвали функцию')
}
module.exports = te;

var co = require('gulp-cl-v');
var te = new co('/foo/file');

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    te.watr();// так получится
});
```

P.S. Почитайте про методы и прототипы в js, как таковые модули node.js здесь не причем.